# How does this syntax compile?

Tags: c++, syntax, lambda

I was messing around with lambdas. for those that don't know, they look like this:

```
[] () { };
```

I removed the parentheses and it still compiles.

```
[] {};
```

How is this so?

Comment: special syntax for lambda without argument.

Comment: Because it is so. Are you going to ask how every other piece of perfectly valid C++ compiles? :)

Answer (score 3):

Quoth the standard,

> If a *lambda-expression* does not include a *lambda-declarator,* it is as if the *lambda-declarator* were `()`.

([expr.prim.lambda]/4 in C++11)

Answer (score 3):

A lambda declarator is optional. §5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda]

> lambda-expression:
>       lambda-introducer **lambda-declarator<sub>opt</sub>** compound-statement

Where a *lambda-declarator* is:

> lambda-declarator:
>       ( parameter-declaration-clause ) mutable<sub>opt</sub>
>       exception-specification<sub>opt</sub> attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> trailing-return-type<sub>opt</sub>

It also says in §5.1.2/4;

> If a *lambda-expression* does not include a lambda-declarator, it is as if the *lambda-declarator* were `()`.